# What is the connection between Rails and Nine / 9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are many Rails focused companies that uses "Nine" or 9 in its name.

Some examples:

- **Nine** Fold - https://ninefold.com/
- Any **nines** - http://www.anynines.com/
- **9** elements - http://web.9elements.com/

What is the connection between Rails and Nine / 9 ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

Comment: There is no connection.